# Using both < and > operators when redirecting command line output

Tags: batch-file, cmd

My batch is supposed to diff the output between two programs using given input data. You can imagine that I'm testing whether certain task has been implemented properly:

```
compareout.bat implementation.exe correct_implementation.exe test_data.txt
```

The program should run the commands using the test data and compare their output. I can save command output using this:

```
ping 8.8.8.8 /t >pinglog.txt
```

I can send file contents to stdin using this:

```
implementation.txt < testdata.txt
```

But how should I use both operators at once?

Comment: http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's as simple as using the operator and the argument. To take a simplistic example:

```
cat <input.txt >output.txt
```

Of course, it only really applies when you've a command that reads `STDIN` and writes `STDOUT` - which doesn't really apply to `ping`.

But what *you're* doing seems to be running two executables and diffing their output. That's a little more complicated - feeding them both to `STDOUT` is easy. Feeding them to two separate `STDOUT`s and diffing them is harder. I'm not actually sure you can on a Windows platform - with Linux, I'd suggest redirecting `STDOUT` of the two different commands to different file descriptors. (E.g. rather than using `STDIN`/`STDOUT`/`STDERR` create an extra set of file descriptors )

Something like:

```
diff <(command1) <(command2)
```

Comment: I am actually comfortable with saving the output in temporary files and feeding these to diff. Especially since I might need to check the files out if later.